# Trigger cria registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger

O trigger de "update" no Mysql cria 8 registros a cada atualização.
O primeiro registro é o antigo, os 7 seguintes são cópias da alteração.
Como deixo somente o antigo e o editado?

Tentei colocar chave UNIQUE na *datetime* da tabela "historico", porém gera um erro. Só que também não é essa solução que preciso. Não posso nomear uma chave unique, pois um mesmo registro pode ser alterado várias vezes.

Código inserido no PhpMyAdmin:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `placasptc`.`update_bds`//
CREATE TRIGGER `placasptc`.`update_bds` BEFORE UPDATE ON `placasptc`.`bds`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
insert into historico
set hist_action ='update',
bkp_ID = old.ID,
bkp_empresa = old.empresa,
bkp_prefixo = old.prefixo,
bkp_placa = old.placa,
hist_modificado = now(),
hist_usuario = Current_user();
end
```

Comment: certo que o erro não é da trigger, mas sim de onde você realiza o comando

Comment: Provavelmente esse update está sendo executado mais de uma vez. Verifique os locais que você executa ele, e observe para ver se em algum momento esse UPDATE não é chamado para outro campo a não ser a chave primaria, caso tenha você tem a probabilidade de estar atualizando vários registros

Comment: Achei. To fazendo pelo Dreamweaver, e toda vez que eu criava uma comunicação com o banco de dados criava uma nova operação, só que quando eu deletava, a operação continuava no código fonte. Removi tudo e funcionou. Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda.